# How to plot two different dataframe columns at time based on the same datetime x-axis

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, plot, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe like this:

```
        Date  Influenza[it]  Febbre[it]  Cefalea[it]  Paracetamolo[it]  \
0    2008-01            989        2395         1291              2933   
1    2008-02            962        2553         1360              2547   
2    2008-03           1029        2309         1401              2735   
3    2008-04           1031        2399         1137              2296    

     Unnamed: 6 tot_incidence  
0           NaN          4.56  
1           NaN          5.98  
2           NaN          6.54  
3           NaN          6.95
```

I'd like to plot different figures with on x-axis the `Date` column and the y-axis the `Influenza[it]` column and another column like `Febbre[it]`. Then again x-axis the `Date` column, y-axis `Influenza[it]` column and another column (ex. `Paracetamolo[it]`) and so on. I'm trying to figure out if there is a fast way to make it without completely manipulate the dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply plot 3 different subplots.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dic = {"Date" : ["2008-01","2008-02", "2008-03", "2008-04"],
       "Influenza[it]" : [989,962,1029,1031],
        "Febbre[it]" : [2395,2553,2309,2399],
        "Cefalea[it]" : [1291,1360,1401,1137],
        "Paracetamolo[it]" : [2933,2547,2735,2296]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
#optionally convert to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(13,7))
df.plot(x="Date", y=["Influenza[it]","Febbre[it]" ], ax=ax[0])
df.plot(x="Date", y=["Influenza[it]","Cefalea[it]" ], ax=ax[1])
df.plot(x="Date", y=["Influenza[it]","Paracetamolo[it]" ], ax=ax[2])

#optionally equalize yaxis limits
for a in ax:
    a.set_ylim([800, 3000])

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you want to plot each plot separately in a jupyter notebook, the following might do what you want.
Additionally we convert the dates from format `year-week` to a datetime to be able to plot them with matplotlib.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dic = {"Date" : ["2008-01","2008-02", "2008-03", "2008-04"],
       "Influenza[it]" : [989,962,1029,1031],
        "Febbre[it]" : [2395,2553,2309,2399],
        "Cefalea[it]" : [1291,1360,1401,1137],
        "Paracetamolo[it]" : [2933,2547,2735,2296]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
#convert to datetime, format year-week -> date (monday of that week)
df['Date'] = [ date + "-1" for date in df['Date']] # add "-1" indicating monday of that week
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y-%W-%w")

cols = ["Febbre[it]", "Cefalea[it]", "Paracetamolo[it]"]
for col in cols:
    plt.close()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    ax.set_ylim([800, 3000])
    ax.plot(df.Date, df["Influenza[it]"], label="Influenza[it]")
    ax.plot(df.Date, df[col], label=col)
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Nice! I'd like to make it without writing everytime a line because i have to use many columns but it's good anyway! I'm plotting in the jupiter notebook and i ask you if there is a way to make the subplots one after the other and not side by side (i mean figures with the largest x-axis and small y-axis)

Comment: This is an important piece of information that should be part of the question. I updated the answer.

Comment: I tried with edited code but i receive an error to this line 'ax.plot(df.Date, df["Influenza[it]"], label="Influenza[it]")' : 'ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2016-16'. In case i run 'df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])' i receive this error 'ValueError: month must be in 1..12'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the comment: Using matplotib you need to use datetimes - it's not optional anymore. The error that you get, makes sense, since "2016-16" is no valid date. Are you expecting that matplotlib invents 4 new months in the year or did I misunderstand the datetime format you are using?

Comment: Well that is.. another piece of information that should be part of the question. Is your data covering several years? Are dates equally spaced, i.e. is every week between the first and last entry present? Would you rather have the date axes in weeks or in normal dates (like every monday of that specific week)?

Comment: Thanks, just the line 'df['Date'] = [ date + "-1" for date in df['Date']]' returns an error: 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'str'' but that's not a problem. Hoping to not be annoying, I'd like to know only now if there is a way to resize the subplots to make them large horizontally and small vertically

Comment: If the `date` already is a timestamp, you might need to convert it to a string first, then add the weekday and then convert it back to datetime. the figure size can be set via the `figsize` argument. You might want to try something like `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(16,4))`.

Comment: Great it works, i'll try then to figure out about the date. Thanks a lot!